# Does continuous inspection still work with Sonar 5.1.X?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm trying to run a preview analysis for a (Java) project of ours with SonarQube 5.1.1. I am able to get a local report generated, however I get no coverage data, and I also get the message `[INFO] [XX:YY:ZZ.ZZZ] Build Breaker plugin is no more supported in preview/incremental mode`.

If I check [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin), the page says that `Starting with SonarQube 5.1, the Build Breaker plugin does not work any longer in the preview & incremental modes.`.

I'm confused - I thought that for continuous inspection one needs the build breaker plugin. Is that no longer so? Has the concept in SonarQube changed?

Why am I not getting coverage data when running a preview analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you've read this, but continuous inspection is not specifically related to the preview/incremental mode nor to the build breaker plugin - it's not even related to SonarQube (even though it has been [pushed by SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/features/continuous-inspection/) from the very beginning).

Here are the key points:

- Continuous inspection is about analyzing your code as often as you can in order to monitor (and eventually improve) the quality of your code. Whatever the tool.
- On SonarQube, this means running analyses that will push information on the server so that you can monitor what's going on and take the required actions for your application portfolio.

Obviously, when you are a developer, you'd like to manage those issues early, before they even get pushed to the source code repository. But experience tells us that preventing any code push because of issues is a bad pattern - because some issues might be false-positive or not relevant in the context (and still you want - and have the right, to push your code). This is why we feel that the build breaker plugin is not aligned with all this, and it will be replaced in upcoming versions of SQ by native features that match better these concepts:

- Very efficient code analysis to display issues in the IDE at the speed of light - but without computing metrics
- Preview mode that will compute everything and make it possible to check quality gate before pushing code to the source code repository - without impacting the results on the server

  - and in this case, using some specific information found in the logs, it will be possible for a CI to fail a build

Comment: Nice to ear that some day, preview mode will be able to check quality gate. By the way, for now we are stuck between waiting upcoming versions (when will this be ready ?) or going back to SonarQube 5.0, right ?

Comment: The built in Build Breaker Plugin for SonarQube has retired in 5.1 release. This is a workaround to achieve the same using SonarQube REST APIs. https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/sonarqube-build-breaker

Comment: Hi Fabrice, Thanks for the information. I think it is worth to add a link to build breaker plugin's page in help document, as people may has similar confusion when they see this plugin is deprecated. In my opinion, build breaker is important to large, process-centric organization. For example in my organization we relies on builder breaker to block code submission if blocker issue (we defined a minimal quality gate which should never be broken) is found in incremental scan. Do you think our case is still valid, or SonarQube has different opinion about the usage?

Comment: @Skywolf The use case is perfectly valid, and in SonarQube 5.3, we have developed WS to be able to write a build breaker strategy on your own. We are currently documenting this, it will be available with the release of SQ 5.3 in January. Feel free to ping me again here so that I update the post!

Comment: Thanks Fabrice! We will live with SonarQube 4.x till new mechanism is verified. And many thanks for your team to make such a fabulous tool/platform!